# What method would be used in DbDataRecord for validating if the column exist?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I want to validate if the field really exist in the table in the database. I have used the SqlDataReader class for the reading of data. After assigning the value to the SqlDataReader I made a loop to iterate each record using foreach. Here is the sample code.

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();

SqlDataReader sqlDr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

Foreach(DbDataRecord record in sqlDr)
{
    // Validate if the value is not null and (I want to validate if this field really exist in the table)
    if(record["MyField1"].GetType().ToString() == "System.DBNull")
    {
        // Statement here
    }
}
```

I hope for a kind answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write an `extension` method which iterates thru each fields in the reader and return true/false.

```
public static class DataRecordExtensions
{
    public static bool HasColumn(this IDataRecord dr, string columnName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            if (dr.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then call it like this

```
if (objReader.HasColumn("FirstName")
{
  //Column exist. So lets read the value
   someobject.Name= objReader.GetString(objReader.GetOrdinal("FirstName"));
}
```

Comment: I was looking for this, thanks a lot...  :(  In my case can't use like extensions because I'm in framework 1.1 ..  ¬¬

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the code similar to that of your question you **could** do it this way:

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
{
    SqlDataReader sqlDr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

    if (!sqlDr.Read()) return;

    HashSet<string> fieldNames = new HashSet<string>(sqlDr.FieldCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < sqlDr.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        fieldNames.Add(sqlDr.GetName(i));
    }

    if (!fieldNames.Contains("MyField1") || !fieldNames.Contains("MyField2"))
    {
        // do something here
    }
}
```